# If I used either javascript or Jquery to insert a value into an html element from an input text , Would it be saved?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

If I have a form like that :

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="link" class="link"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="go"/>
</form>
```

Then I insert the value of the input text called "link" into another html element via Javascript or Jquery when the form is submitted :

```
<span class="link_val"></span>

if(isset($_POST['go'])){
 echo "<script> $('link_val').val() = $('.link').val() </script>";
}
```

Then If I refresh the page or reopen it would the span value remain the last value inserted to the input ? or that would require a database to save the value of the input ?

Comment: for a value yes, for a new input, it will be posted, but saved or not it depends on what you do with the `$_POST`.

Comment: First of all, refreshing the page clears sent form params. PHP processing starts fresh each time the page is opened, unless you use sessions. Secondly, I'm not seeing you insert the value anywhere, but doing so is even more fleeting than sending it to PHP; refreshing the page will reload it from the server, so all client-side changes are gone. (also jQuery is just JavaScript). If you want persistent changes, you have to store them on the server. In a file, or database.

Comment: @ChrisG , first , Can I save a value to a session or cookie then get whenever I want?

Comment: @ChrisG second , What do you mean by store them on the server?

Comment: Like I said, "In a file, or database". Using PHP commands.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery .val is equivalent to the Javascript .value and it can be used on input elements.
If you would change the text inside a paragraph you should use jQuery .html or Javascript .innerHTML.
I suggest to modify your code as follows:

```
<span class="link_val"></span>

if(isset($_POST['go'])){
 echo "<script> $('link_val').html() = $('.link').val() </script>";
}
```